# Ruby gem to generate GIF CSS sprites from PNGs?

Tags: css, ruby, rubygems, png, css-sprites

Is there a Ruby gem that can generate CSS sprites from PNG images by combining them into a GIF?

I am looking for one that supports command line. I found several but they either work only with Rails or can only produce PNG sprites, never gifs.

Comment: Someone's got to ask: *Why?* There's a reason you can't find a tool for this, and it's that there's no reason to use GIFs instead of PNGs (except for the occasional GIF animation but that obviously isn't your use case).

Comment: I ran several tools (including those that offer various compression methods) and the smallest of the resulting PNGs was twice the size of the GIF version I created through online tools. In this particular instance I need to churn out sprites for high-traffic sales pages where speed is hugely important and data-uri is not an option because some customers use older browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another big caveat with GIF is that you're limited to a 256-color palette, which is often fine for a single image but could be problematic if your sprites vary widely in palette. Regardless...

[css_sprite](https://github.com/flyerhzm/css_sprite) (the first result for [this gem search](http://rubygems.org/search?query=css+sprite)) looks like your best bet.

You probably found it on your own and disregarded it because it *appears* to depend on Rails. However, peeking at the code shows that [in fact it doesn't](https://github.com/flyerhzm/css_sprite/blob/master/lib/automatic.rb#L4-9). Running it as specified should work as long as your configuration file is specified.*

*It looks like the `css_sprite:build` Rake task *might* break without Rails (because it doesn't require `lib/automatic.rb`, which "fakes" `Rails.root`) but using `rake css_sprite:start` should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, I gave it a try but unfortunately both of those commands show the error `Don't know how to build task 'css_sprite:start'`